# How to add a Branch to An Already Existing TTree: ROOT

Tags: c++, tree, root-framework

I have an existing TTree after doing a simulation. I would like to add a Branch to this TTree and I want to call it Muon.Mass to the tree. I would also want to give the Muon.Mass branch a value of 0.1.

How can I write that?

I have seen how to create TTrees from scratch and to have branches of different variables. But I am not sure exactly what to do when I already have a TTree.

Comment: your question is very unclear, for example what's Muon.Mass? what do you mean by branch values? and you said you have seen how to create trees, what does that mean? where did you see, is this a thing to see? I can go on, but the point is, clearly state your question to get help!

Comment: @usernew The `root` tag refers to the `root` user on Unix systems. The tag for CERN's ROOT framework is `root-framework`. I allowed myself to go through your questions and fix the tags. Use the correct tag the next time. That will make it more likely that users knowledgeable about ROOT will actually see your questions. Please, in the future, read the tag description before you choose a tag.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for pointing that out and fixing it. I will make sure to put in the right tag next time

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `TTree::Branch` method on an existing TTree the same way as for a new TTree. Just for filling you need to ensure you only fill the branch. (this is a strongly cut down example from https://github.com/pseyfert/tmva-branch-adder)

```cpp
void AddABranch(TTree* tree) {
  Float_t my_local_variable;
  TBranch* my_new_branch = tree->AddBranch( ... /* use address of my_local_variable */ );
  for (Long64_t entry = 0 ; entry < tree->GetEntries() ; ++e ) {
    tree->GetEntry();
    /* something to compute my_local_variable */
    my_new_branch->Fill();
  }
}
```

As alternative you might want to look at the root tutorials for tree friends.

As a side note, depending what you want to do with the tree / whom you give the tree to, I advise against using `.` in branch names as they cause headache when running `MakeClass` (branch names can contain periods, but c++ variables can't, so the automatically generated class members for each branch will undergo character replacement).